# I am not able to open URL using driver.get("URL") in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am not able to open URL using driver.get("URL") in selenium web driver using firefox version 49.0.1.
The error I am getting is:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output

Comment: add some more details,  are you facing any error ?

Comment: Yes. PFB error that i am getting.
"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output"

Comment: I think you are using old selenium jar files please update to latest one and use `geckodriver` to connect with firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download `geckodriver.exe` from [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) link, you can not run firefox 49.0 without gecko driver. After download unzip it and store in any location on you machine then follow this code. Use Selenium version 3.0.1 for this.
If you are using older version of selenium then you have to use

```
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

in place of

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Download gecko driver from this link: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe"); // you have to select you path of gecko driver where you placed it after download and unzip.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.hotmail.com");
```

Comment: This woked for me. Will it work for later version of 49.o of mozilla. And also i would like to know why to use geckodriver.exe(for more than 49 version of mozilla) and WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();(for older selenium version)?